# How can I get ListView Items to take up all available space?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a `ListView` that takes up the entire width of the screen - I want the items to take up all available space. There will be a maximum of 4 per "screen". I will then want to put the ListView into a FlipView and take 4 items each "flip".

So far I have set the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

This gives me the four columns, but puts all items into the first column. Perhaps this isn't the right method? If it is the right method, how do I set the column they should be in? Add a value to my object which equals `"[Index in Collection] % 4"` and set the ItemTemplate `Grid.Column` to this value?

This all seems a bit too complicated to do something which I imagine might be quite a bit more simple - is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the following article,

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/11/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol/

Comment: Thanks - while not a perfect answer, this lead me to doing my own thing and set each new item to a new column

Comment: They updated the article [link](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html) for anyone looking